# Find the number of solutions of $\cos x=\frac{\lvert x \rvert}{80}$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the number of solution of $\cos x=\frac{\lvert x \rvert}{80}$

Domain of $x$ is $[0,\pi]$ and the range of $x$ is $[-80,80]$. I am not able to proceed.

Comment: Functions have domains and ranges, $x$ is an independent(ish) variable so I'm guessing $[0,\pi]$ is the set of values you can plug into $x$, correct?

Comment: try graphing $y = \cos x$ and $y = \frac {|x|}{80}$ How many times within your domain of x do the curves intersect?

Comment: $\cos(x)$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $[0, \pi]$ whereas $\displaystyle \frac{x}{80}$ is strictly increasing.  So if there is an intersection, there can be only one.  The [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), if you're familiar with it, can help you conclude that an intersection does occur.

Comment: What does it mean that the range of $x$ is $[-80,80]$?

Comment: I think that the request is simply to find the number of all solutions. LHS and RHS are even fuctions so it’s enough to solve $\cos x=x/80$ for positive $x$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Calculate the number of full cosine "hills" from 0 to 80 (12). Each such hill gives two zeros. And you have one 'semi-hill' between 0 and $\pi/2$. So the total number of zeros is 12$\cdot$2+1=25 for $x>0$. Multiply this by 2 (because LHS and RHS a are symmetric with respect to $y$-axis) and you get 50 as the final answer.